# Dart - How to create custom types on the fly like in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, dart, types, custom-type

I want to create a custom type in Dart like I would do in typescript. This type should be a subtype of String, accepting only some values.

For example, in Typescript I would do:

```
type myType = 'HELLO' | 'WORLD' | '!'
```

How can I do the same stuff in Dart?

Comment: I'm not a Dart user so I read the documentation and searched up a few things, and based on what I found I don't think you can define unions of string literals as a type. However I do think you should consider using enums instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Original Answer (see updates below)**: This isn't possible at the language level in Dart - There are a couple alternatives though.

You could simply define an enum along with a method to derive a string from your enum:

```
enum MyType {
  hello,
  world,
  exclamationPoint,
}

String myTypeToString(MyType value) {
  switch (value) {
    case MyType.hello: 
      return 'HELLO';
    case MyType.world: 
      return 'WORLD';
    case MyType.exclamationPoint: 
      return '!';
  }
}
```

**Update 2**: In Dart 3 we have yet another way, using sealed classes:

```dart
sealed class MyType {
  @override
  String toString() {
    return switch (this) {
        Hello() => "Hello",
        World() => "world",
        Exclamation() => "!"
    };
  }
}

class Hello extends MyType {}
class World extends MyType {}
class Exclamation extends MyType {}
```

https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#sealed

---

**Old Update**: Now that Dart 2.17 supports declaring methods on enums, it's possible to do this a bit more cleanly than in my original answer:

```
enum MyType {
  hello,
  world,
  exclamationPoint;

  @override
  String toString() {
    switch (this) {
      case MyType.hello: 
        return 'HELLO';
      case MyType.world: 
        return 'WORLD';
      case MyType.exclamationPoint: 
        return '!';
    }
  }
}
```

---

Or you could define a class with three named constructors, and override the toString method:

```
class MyType {
  final String _value;

  MyType.hello(): _value = 'HELLO';
  MyType.world(): _value = 'WORLD';
  MyType.exclamationPoint(): _value = '!';

  @override
  String toString() {
    return _value;
  }
}

// Usage:
void main() {
  final hello = MyType.hello();
  final world = MyType.world();
  final punctuation = MyType.exclamationPoint();

  // Prints "HELLO, WORLD!"
  print("$hello, $world$punctuation");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, today you can use `typedefs` from `2.13` dart version

```dart
typedef IntList = List<int>;
IntList il = [1, 2, 3];
```

https://dart.dev/language/typedefs

Comment: Code-only answers should be updated to explain how the code resolves the question, further guidance can be found in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to enforce custom types in Dart is to use assertions in a constructor (when your custom type is being used).

```dart
class SomeClass {
  final String someVariable
  SomeClass(this.someVariable) : <initializer goes here>;
}
```

The initializer (the part after the colon at the end of the constructor) executes before the constructor itself, so custom requirements for your constructor variables can go there.

We use an assertion rather than an exception, since assertions throw errors that we want to catch in our code before production, rather than exceptions that we want to handle at runtime.

Let's say we have a class called `Student` that has a required field called `id`. The data type of `id` is `String`, *but* we want to enforce a rule that says a student id must be a 24 character hexadecimal string.

Like you say, the natural choice in TypeScript would be to create a custom type using a [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) or [template literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) and use that as the argument type when using a student id in a function *and* when instantiating a `Student`. Dart doesn't let us create custom data types in the same way (though there is the [typedef](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs) type alias), but it does let us make assertions about the *values* of data types when we're trying to use them.

```dart
void main() {
  
  const validId = 'a52f5a6d7b46bffe9f5ec08f';
  const invalidId = 'thisisnotavalidid';
  
  // student1 throws no errors at development time, compile time, or runtime
  final student1 = Student(id: validId, fullName: 'Jimmy Beans');
  
  // student2 throws no errors at development time, but throws an
  // AssertionError (in debug mode) at runtime when trying to 
  // instantiate Student() with an invalid id.
  final student2 = Student(id: invalidId, fullName: 'Bimmy Jeans');
  
  print(student1.toString());
}

// 24 hexadecimal characters
const String studentIdPattern = r'^[a-f\d]{24}$';

class Student {
  
  final String id;
  final String fullName;
    
  Student({
    required this.id,
    required this.fullName,
  }) : assert(RegExp(studentIdPattern, caseSensitive: false).hasMatch(id));
  
  @override
  toString() {
    return "Instance of 'Student': {id: $id, fullName: $fullName}";
  }
}
```

[Run this code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b1d96dead67f35a7f86ecb041b1f84a0)

Basically, we declare a regular expression pattern `r'^[a-f\d]{24}$'` for our 24 character hex string (it can be in the student.dart library/file or in some config file) and add an initializer to the default `Student()` constructor in the form of an `assert()` function call.

When the `Student()` constructor is called, the initializer runs first and checks that the `id` argument that has been passed in is valid.

Some additional notes regarding your specific example:

- the regex pattern to use would be `r'^(HELLO)|(WORLD)$'`
- **that `assert()` call can be made in other places in the code** where it matters what the value of the `String` type is; it doesn't have to be in an initializer.
- this method does *not* throw errors in a linter by default (this is intentional on the part of the Dart devs). Make sure you run your code in a debugger, emulator, or test suite in order to trigger the assertions.
- for more complicated custom types, there's a way to use `Map<KeyClass, ValueClass>` as a "custom type" and enums or classes for `KeyClass` and `ValueClass` in a way that's comparable to TypeScript types, but it's overkill for simple patterns.